# Key Value Match Group Regex where Delimiters can also be contained in quote-enclosed values

Tags: regex, key-value

I am tasked with creating a regular expression against a key/value pair formatted data set. The regex must contain two match groups, one for the key, one for the value.

The key/value pairs are comma-delimited. Where I am struggling is, the values (i.e. the key=**value**) can contain commas. When this is the case, the values are quote-enclosed or 'text-qualified'.

I have no control over the format of the data.

I am close, but my regex fails in the case of quote-enclosed values that contain commas.

Here is what I have tried (https://regex101.com/r/jkK1fT/2):

```
([^=]*)=\"?([A-Za-z\d:\-\s\.]*)\"?,
```

And here are some sample lines:

```
Date=2017-06-29 03:10:00.850 -700 PDT,host=superrad.host,fooVals="12.0,18.0,24.0,36.0,48.0,54.0",origin_ip="FOO: [33.77.254.23]:39562->[222.11.110.111]",foo=bar
Date=2017-06-11 02:30:03.823 -900 PDT,host=superrad.host,fooVals="0.0,22.0,24.0,3.0,4.0,54.0",origin_ip="FOO: [33.77.254.23]:39562->[333.11.22.28]",foo=baz
```

How can I complete my regex so that the second capture group (the one for 'values') can extract the optionally-quote enclosed text, especially when it contains commas, in this case my delimiter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
([\w_]+)=\"(.+?)\"|([\w:\- \.]+)
```

- `([\w_]+)` retrieves keys.
- `\"(.+?)\"` retrieves values enclosed by `"`.
- `[\w:\-\s\.]+` retrieves values except for values enclosed by `"`
- `\s` is included not only space, but also newline character. So I used  instead of `\s`.

https://regex101.com/r/4jsmYp/2

If you want to separate each line for your data, you can also use `([\w_]+)=\"(.+?)\"|[\w:\-\s\.\[\]>]+`.

Comment: Thanks :) While this was helpful and the break down is much appreciated, it does not exclude double quotes from the optionally-double quoted keys, see key fooVals. I probably should have been more specific. Still, I can expand on your approach, thank you again.

Comment: @gpanda Thank you for your comment. I have misunderstand your question. I'm sorry. I updated my answer. Please confirm it. I used ``([\w_]+)=\"(.+?)\"|([\w:\- \.]+)`` and  https://regex101.com/r/4jsmYp/2

Comment: @gpanda As an other sample, how about this? ``([^=]*)=[\"]?([^\"=]+)[\"]?[,\n]`` https://regex101.com/r/4jsmYp/3 I modified used your regex. By modifying ``,`` to ``[,\n]``, ``foo=bar`` can be also retrieved. I could study from your question. Thank you.

Comment: @gpanda Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This met my needs, thanks for anyone who took time to take a look.

```
([^=]*)=[\"\s]?([^\"=]*)[\"]?,
```